# getcwd() returns NULL after new pointer is created

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getcwd

I've just started learning linux and C, please don't judge me strictly.

I'm trying to find a current working directory and to open file in this directory to find a specific word. It gives correct cwd if I find only cwd, but when I added while loop cwd is null.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
main(){
char *buff;
char *currentDir =getcwd(buff,PATH_MAX);

printf("Current directory: %s\n",currentDir);

FILE *file;
char *filename = "profile";
file = fopen(filename,"r");
if(file == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr,"File %s wasn't found\n",filename);
}

while(1)
{
    char buffer[80];
    char *token;
    fgets(buffer,80,file);
    if(feof(file))
    {break;}
    else{
    *token = strtok(buffer,"=");
        if(strcmp(token,"HOME")==1);
        {
        printf("HOME token is found");
        } 
    }
free(token);
}

fclose(file);
}
```

The output:
Current directory: (null)
Segmentation fault

Comment: install ddd debugger it'll help you

Comment: also you cannot declare FILE* char * etc after printf statement

Comment: @BhavikShah You've been able to mix variable declarations and code in standard C since C99 (and before that as an extension on many compilers).

Comment: I rolled back you latest edit, as it rendered my answer ununderstandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`buff` is pointing to random memory.

You might like to declare `buff` like so:

```
char buff[PATH_MAX] = "";
```

---

If on Linux then one can alternatively let `getcwd()` allocate the memory needed by doing so:

```
char * currentDir = getcwd(NULL, 0);
```

`currentDir` needs to be passed to `free()` when done with it, and `buff` is not needed then.

Comment: `buffer` is initialized with the call to `fgets()`. So, no problem there.

Comment: Pardon me, what are you referring too, please? @OlafDietsche

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I mixed up `buff` and `buffer`. But the same holds here. No need to initialize with `= ""`, because `buff` is initialized with the call to `getcwd()`.

Comment: `buff` might be left uninitialised if `getcwd()` failed. @OlafDietsche

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line:

> free(token);

`token` points into `buffer`, which is on the stack. So, no need to free it.

Another bug is:

> *token = strtok(buffer,"=");

`strtok()` returns a `char*`, so this should read:

```
token = strtok(buffer,"=");
```

You should also modify your loop to:

```
#include <string.h>

...
char buffer[80];
while (fgets(buffer,80,file)) {
    char *token = strtok(buffer,"=");
    if (strcmp(token,"HOME") == 0);
    {
        printf("HOME token is found");
    }
...
```

Comment: thanks Olaf. I see why I have bug with token initialisation. I edited it, but compiler says that the line  "char *token = strtok(buffer,"=");" assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Ok, I missed that. You need to include `string.h`. Also change your `strcmp()` to `== 0`, because 1 means greater, 0 equal and -1 less than.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` includes the declarations for `strtok(), strcmp(), ...`. If you use a function without declaration, the compiler assumes the return value is `int`, which is wrong in this case: `char*strtok(char*, const char*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Small function to get current directory:

```
void get_working_dir(void) 
{
    char buf[PATH_MAX];

    if (getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf)) == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Err.:(%d) - %s: curr. workdir\n", errno,strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* print current directory */
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Invoke function with:

```
get_working_dir();
```

Comment: Calling exit on failure is not an expected behavior - I would not recommend doing so without a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem so i took a look to the man pages where is was said that the getcpw() syscall will malloc the buffer if it is NULL.
I think the problem is that your buffer is not nulled so try to initiallize it with the NULL pointer

```
    char *buff=NULL;
    buff=getcwd(buff,PATH_MAX);
```